# Android transparent background for pdf using mupdf

Tags: android, transparent, mupdf

I am using mupdf for rendering pdf in my android app. The issue that I'm facing is that even while reading a pdf with transparent background, it is showing white background.
How can I rectify this error ? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: PDF doesn't have a 'transparent background', the media for a PDF file is assumed to be white and opaque. You draw the PDF content onto that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a pdf to have transparent background with MuPDF go to the C program file("mupdf.c") remove the code that sets the background to white and replace it with `fz_clear_pixmap(ctx, pix);`

ie, replace `fz_clear_pixmap_with_value(ctx, pix, 0xff);` with `fz_clear_pixmap(ctx, pix);`

after editing rebuild the ndk, and use it in your android app.